# Split, escaping certain splits

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that contains multiple questions and answers and is organised like a CSV. So to get all these questions and answers separated a simple split using the comma as the delimiter should separate this easily.

Unfortunately, there are some values that use the comma as the decimal separator. Is there a way to escape the split for those occurrences?

Fortunately, my data can be split using ", " as separator, but if this wouldn't be the case, would there still be a solution besides manually replacing the decimal delimiter from a comma to a dot?

Example:

"Price: 0,09,Quantity: 12,Sold: Yes"
Using Split("Price: 0,09,Quantity: 12,Sold: Yes",",") would yield:

Price: 0
09
Quantity: 12
Sold: Yes

Comment: This exact issue is why I like to use a delimiter that is highly unlikely to "naturally" occur, like "<>" or something of that sort.  In terms of escaping the unintended delimiters, I think you will need to use replace to change the intended delimiters to something else and use some clever string logic to detect which should be replaced

Comment: That would ofcourse be the most desired option. But unfortunately you can't always decide the delimiter and therefore have to deal with what third parties give you.

Comment: Are the not-delimiter-commas delimited by something themselves e.g. `"Tom, Bob and Harry each have $1, how many $ in total?","$9"` ?

Comment: If you can consider a numeric character as such a delimiter then yes. For example: "Price: 0,09,Quantity 12,Sold: Yes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility, given this test data, is to loop through the array after splitting, and whenever there's no `:` in the string, add this entry to the previous one.

The function that does this might look like this:

```
Public Function CleanUpSeparator(celldata As String) As String()
    Dim ret() As String
    Dim tmp() As String
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    tmp = Split(celldata, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(tmp)
        If InStr(1, tmp(i), ":") < 1 Then
            ' Put this value on the previous line, and restore the comma
            tmp(i - 1) = tmp(i - 1) & "," & tmp(i)
            tmp(i) = ""
        End If
    Next i

    j = 0
    ReDim ret(j)
    For i = 0 To UBound(tmp)
        If tmp(i) <> "" Then
            ret(j) = tmp(i)
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve ret(j)
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve ret(j - 1)

    CleanUpSeparator = ret
End Function
```

Note that there's room for improvement by making the separator caharacters `:` and `,` into parameters, for instance.

Comment: That is indeed a neat solution. I wonder if there would be anything shorter though?

Comment: Don't see how.. You could skip the second iteration, and handle empty values in the function that calls this, i.e. when using the data. I prefer to clean that sort of thing out a the source. Other than that, VB doesn't have great support for removing array entries.

Comment: I don't mean your code in specific, its written fairly efficient and clean. Just for the problem in general, does there exist a shorter solution.

Comment: Yep, using another separator. Could be as easy as a semicolon or pipe (`;`, `|`) instead of colon. But you said you can't control the sep, shame...

Answer (score 0):

I spent the last 24 hours or so puzzling over what I THINK is a completely analogous problem, so I'll share my solution here.  Forgive me if I'm wrong about the applicability of my solution to this question. :-)

My Problem: I have a SharePoint list in which teachers (I'm an elementary school technology specialist) enter end-of-year award certificates for me to print.  Teachers can enter multiple students' names for a given award, separating each name using a comma.  I have a VBA macro in Access that turns each name into a separate record for mail merging.  Okay, I lied.  That was more of a story.  HERE'S the problem: How can teachers add a student name like Hank Williams, Jr. (note the comma) without having the comma cause "Jr." to be interpreted as a separate student in my macro?

The full contents of the (SharePoint exported to Excel) field "Students" are stored within the macro in a variable called strStudentsBeforeSplit, and this string is eventually split with this statement:

strStudents = Split(strStudentsBeforeSplit, ",", -1, vbTextCompare)

So there's the problem, really.  The Split function is using a comma as a separator, but poor student Hank Williams, Jr. has a comma in his name.  What to do?

I spent a long time trying to figure out how to escape the comma.  If this is possible, I never figured it out.

Lots of forum posts suggested using a different character as the separator.  That's okay, I guess, but here's the solution I came up with:

1. Replace only the special commas preceding "Jr" with a different, uncommon character BEFORE the Split function runs.
2. Swap back to the commas after Split runs.

That's really the end of my post, but here are the lines from my macro that accomplish step 1.  This may or may not be of interest because it really just deals with the minutiae of making the swap.   Note that the code handles several different (mostly wrong) ways my teachers might type the "Jr" part of the name.

```
'Dealing with the comma before Jr.  This will handle ", Jr." and ", Jr" and " Jr." and " Jr".
'Replaces the comma with ~ because commas are used to separate fields in Split function below.
'Will swap ~ back to comma later in UpdateQ_Comma_for_Jr query.
strStudentsBeforeSplit = Replace(strStudentsBeforeSplit, "Jr", "~ Jr.") 'Every Jr gets this treatment regardless of what else is around it.
'Note that because of previous Replace functions a few lines prior, the space between the comma and Jr will have been removed.  This adds it back.
strStudentsBeforeSplit = Replace(strStudentsBeforeSplit, ",~ Jr", "~ Jr") 'If teacher had added a comma, strip it.
strStudentsBeforeSplit = Replace(strStudentsBeforeSplit, " ~ Jr", "~ Jr") 'In cases when teacher added Jr but no comma, remove the (now extra)...
'...space that was before Jr.
```